# Pre Colonial Native American coming of age story about a girl who travels across the country for food

Tags: identification-request

I read this book forever ago.

It is a Native American inspired story about a girl whose village needs food. Her grandmother had a vision and sends her to travel across the country with a man (no real romance there, he was more family friend/guide). I think his name was Coyote something I can’t remember. She encounters many different tribes along the way.

She had a necklace of animal beads that she keeps through all her travels and trades it in the end for children who know how to plant corn, to bring the blessing of corn back across the country to her people to survive a famine. The children lived separate because they were orphans or had some abnormality that set them apart, I remember one had blue eyes. But they still belonged to their people and she had to trade to take the knowledge of corn with them).

Comment: Reminiscent of *Clan of the Cave Bear* saga - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Clan_of_the_Cave_Bear